# Pandas left merge but overwrite with right data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to merge two dataframes, `df2` might have more columns and will always be 1 row. I would like the data from the `df2` row to overwrite the matching row in `df` on `a`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}, 'b': {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 1}, 'b': {0: 90}, 'c': {0: 76}})


>>> df
   a  b
0  0  3
1  1  4
2  2  5

>>> df2
   a  b   c
0  1  90  76
```

The desired output:

```
   a    b   c
0  0    3   NaN
1  1    90  76 
2  2    5   NaN
```

I have tried merge left but this creates two b columns (`b_x` and `b_y`):

```
>>> pd.merge(df,df2,how='left', on='a')
   a  b_x   b_y     c
0  0    3   NaN   NaN
1  1    4  90.0  76.0
2  2    5   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[`df.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)** here:

```
df2.set_index("a").combine_first(df.set_index("a")).reset_index()
```

Or with merge:

```
out = df.merge(df2,on=['a'],how='left')
out.loc[:,out.columns.str.endswith("_x")] = out.loc[:,
                                    out.columns.str.endswith("_y")].to_numpy()
out = out.groupby(out.columns.str.split("_").str[0],axis=1).first()

print(out)
```

---

```
   a     b     c
0  0   3.0   NaN
1  1  90.0  76.0
2  2   5.0   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hmmmm, what would you do if `on=['a','x']` was required? (If x was another column within the dataframes)

Comment: @Unfitacorn You don't need it in this sutation because you are making 'a' the index in both dataframes and pandas automatically aligns most operations on index.  Therefore, on =  'a' is implied.

Comment: @ScottBoston The reason I ask is because `a` may not always be unique, it may be two columns together that make the row unique. Unless I am misunderstanding dataframe indexes and there can be duplicates?

Comment: @Unfitacorn Ah.. that is a different matter all together. if A is duplicated do you want to join first a only in the df ?  Or exactly how do you want to handle duplicates?

Comment: @Unfitacorn May need to create a pseudo key by cumcouting 'a' such that first 'a' join on first 'a' only.

Comment: @Unfitacorn It is best to accept this solution and create a new question with the duplicate 'a' scenario with expected output.

Comment: @Unfitacorn Updated my answer with `merge`

Comment: [Question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66786090/pandas-left-merge-keeping-data-in-right-dataframe-on-duplicte-columns) due to not realising I was on my very ancient account.