# Pandas left merge keeping data in right dataframe on duplicte columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to merge two dataframes, df2 might have more columns and will always be 1 row. I would like the data from the df2 row to overwrite the matching row in df. NOTE: `ser` and `no` columns together make a row unique.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ser': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2}, 'no': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 2}, 'c': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ser': {0: 1}, 'no': {0: 2}, 'c': {0: 88}, 'd': {0: 90}})


>>> df
   ser  no  c
0    0   0  1
1    0   1  1
2    0   2  1
3    1   0  1
4    1   1  1
5    1   2  1
6    2   0  1
7    2   1  1
8    2   2  1

>>> df2
   ser  no   c   d
0    1   2  88  90
```

I have tried merge left but this creates two c columns (c_x and c_y):

```
>>> pd.merge(df,df2,how='left',on=['ser','no'])
   ser  no  c_x   c_y     d
0    0   0    1   NaN   NaN
1    0   1    1   NaN   NaN
2    0   2    1   NaN   NaN
3    1   0    1   NaN   NaN
4    1   1    1   NaN   NaN
5    1   2    1  88.0  90.0
6    2   0    1   NaN   NaN
7    2   1    1   NaN   NaN
8    2   2    1   NaN   NaN
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
   ser  no    c   d  
0    0   0    1   NaN 
1    0   1    1   NaN  
2    0   2    1   NaN 
3    1   0    1   NaN 
4    1   1    1   NaN 
5    1   2    88  90 
6    2   0    1   NaN
7    2   1    1   NaN
8    2   2    1   NaN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Frankenstein Answer

```
df[['ser', 'no']].merge(df2, 'left').set_axis(df.index).fillna(df)

   ser  no     c     d
0    0   0   1.0   NaN
1    0   1   1.0   NaN
2    0   2   1.0   NaN
3    1   0   1.0   NaN
4    1   1   1.0   NaN
5    1   2  88.0  90.0
6    2   0   1.0   NaN
7    2   1   1.0   NaN
8    2   2   1.0   NaN
```

---

#### Explanation

1. I'm going to merge on the columns `['ser', 'no']` and don't want to specify in the `merge` call.  Also, I don't want goofy duplicate column names like `'c_x'` and `'c_y'` so I slice only columns that I want in common then merge

   ```
    df[['ser', 'no']].merge(df2, 'left')
   ```
2. When I merge, I want only rows from the left dataframe.  However, `merge` usually produces a number of rows vastly different from the original dataframes and therefore produces a new `index`.  However, **NOTE** this is assuming the right dataframe (`df2`) has ***NO DUPLICATES*** with respect `['ser', 'no']` then a `'left'` `merge` should produce the same exact number of rows as the left dataframe (`df`).  But it won't have the same `index` necessarily.  It turns out that in this example it does.  But I don't want to take chances.  So I use `set_axis`

   ```
     set_axis(df.index)
   ```
3. Finally, since the resulting dataframe has the same `index` and `columns` as `df`.  I can fill in the missing bits with:

   ```
   fillna(df)
   ```

Comment: Regarding Explanation 2, AFAIK, left merge returns the data in the same order they occur in the left dataframe. So one would get the same (range)  index, unless there are duplicates in key columns.

Comment: No, I don't think so.  Try: `pd.DataFrame({'Col1': 1}, [*'ABC']).merge(pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1]}), 'left')`  It replaces my perfectly good `['A', 'B', 'C']` index with `[0, 1, 2]`.  For this question, it doesn't show up.  But OPs ***actual*** data might have an index they'd like to preserve.  Or anyone else looking at the Q&A for that matter.

Comment: I agreed, merge always returns ranged index, that's why the `range` was in parenthesis. I was trying to echo the duplicates on `df2`.

Comment: Ohh, I see.  Yeah.  I mentioned that. I'll emphasize it more.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**: What you are looking for is `combine_first`:

```
(df2.set_index(['ser','no'])
    .combine_first(df.set_index(['ser','no']))
    .reset_index()
)
```

You can also try `concat`, which is more similar to `'outer'` merge when the pair `ser,no` are unique valued.

```
pd.concat([df2,df]).groupby(['ser','no'], as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
   ser  no   c     d
0    0   0   1   NaN
1    0   1   1   NaN
2    0   2   1   NaN
3    1   0   1   NaN
4    1   1   1   NaN
5    1   2  88  90.0
6    2   0   1   NaN
7    2   1   1   NaN
8    2   2   1   NaN
```

Comment: @ALollz Actually yes. It's not really a merge per se. Updating.