# How to merge df1 & df2 but only keep the new rows of df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I've been searching up for hours how to resolve my issue but found nothing.
I have 2 dataframes that i want to merge on column X but i want to keep y column from df1 and only add the new rows from df2.
Basically this situation:

df1:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

df2:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| A | 45 |
| B | 37 |
| D | 4 |

desired result:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 4 |

To achieve this, I have tried ;

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['x','y'] , how = 'left')
```

however this does not yield what I need. I have also tried concat but didn't succeed.

The problem seems trivial but I just can't find how to get around it.

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby('x', as_index=False).first()`

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66786090/pandas-left-merge-keeping-data-in-right-dataframe-on-duplicte-columns/66786300?noredirect=1#comment118061718_66786300).

Comment: You can merge the two data frames and then delete duplicate entries. `df.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Thanks Quang, also works !

However Killer, I tried your solution but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to do it with append. You can add the rows from `df2` where the 'x' value isn't in `df1` already.

```
df1 = df1.append(df2[~df2['x'].isin(df1['x'])], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Definitely solved. Have no clue why I didn't think about the append to be honest.