# Merging pandas dataframes, keep all rows and columns, without duplicates. If duplicates, keep left (_x) columns, unless right (_y) column value exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge two Pandas DataFrames. The first dataframe (animals_df) contains the original values, the second dataframe (update_df) contains new values that will replace or update the original values. I want to keep all rows (animals) and columns (metadata about the animals) from both dataframes, but no duplicate rows (animals) or columns.

For the duplicated columns (same as columns found on both dataframes) I want to keep the original columns (suffix with _UPDATE, left) unless no update value was provided in the update_df.

```
animals = [
    {"name": "buddy",
     "animal": "dog",
     "food": "Cat Food"},

    {"name": "dexter",
     "animal": "cat",
     "food": "Cat Food"},

    {"name": "solovino",
     "animal": "dog"}
]
update = [
    # Update food and add brand column
    {"name": "buddy",
     "animal": "dog",
     "food": "dog food",
     "brand": "pet smart"},
    # New animal
    {"name": "micky",
     "animal": "mouse",
     "food": "kids",
     "brand": "disni"}
]

#Create Dataframes
animals_df = pd.DataFrame(animals)
update_df = pd.DataFrame(update)
display(animals_df)
display(update_df)
```

animals_df Output:

```
id  name     animal  food
0   buddy    dog     Cat Food
1   dexter   cat     Cat Food
2   solovino dog     NaN
```

update_df Output:

```
id  name    animal  food      brand
0   buddy   dog     dog food  pet smart
1   micky   mouse   kids      disni
```

This code produces the results I want, but I believe there might be a better and simple solution.

```
y_suffix = '_UPDATE'
animals_updated_df = pd.merge(animals_df, update_df, on=['name', 'animal'],
                               how='outer', suffixes=('', y_suffix))
display(animals_updated_df)
```

animals_updated_df Output:

```
id  name     animal  food      food_UPDATE  brand
0   buddy    dog     Cat Food  dog food     pet smart
1   dexter   cat     Cat Food  NaN          NaN
2   solovino dog     NaN       NaN          NaN
3   micky    mouse   NaN       kids         disni
```

Continue:

```
def update_rows(row, update_columns, suffix):
    """This function replaces the original values from the animals_df
    with the corresponding update value in the update_df.
    if no update value provided, then keep the original value"""

    updated_row = row
    for column in update_columns:
        update_value = row[column]
        if not pd.isna(update_value):
            original_column = column.strip(suffix)
            updated_row[original_column] = update_value
    return updated_row

#Get a list of the columns names with the update values, eg. food_UPDATE
update_columns = animals_updated_df.columns[animals_updated_df.columns.str.contains(y_suffix)].to_list()


#for each row (animal) apply the function update_rows, 
#that will replace the original values with the updated ones.
animals_updated_df = animals_updated_df.apply(lambda x: update_rows(x, update_columns, y_suffix), axis=1)

#Remove the columns with the update values, eg. food_UPDATE
animals_updated_df.drop(update_columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
animals_updated_df
```

animals_updated_df Output:

```
id  name     animal  food      brand
0   buddy    dog     dog food  pet smart
1   dexter   cat     Cat Food  NaN
2   solovino dog     NaN       NaN
3   micky    mouse   kids      disni
```

Do you know how this can be done without the need of a function?

I have also tried the solution on [Pandas left merge keeping data in right dataframe on duplicte columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66786090/pandas-left-merge-keeping-data-in-right-dataframe-on-duplicte-columns)

```
animals_updated_df2 = pd.concat([animals_df, update_df]).groupby(['name', 'animal'], as_index=False).first()
display(animals_updated_df2)
```

But the output is not what I need. The food value for buddy-dog was not updated with "dog food" and for some reason, on a larger dataframe this code results in ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 12176 and the array at index 1 has size 43:

```
id  name     animal  food      brand
0   buddy    dog     Cat Food  pet smart
1   dexter   cat     Cat Food  None
2   micky    mouse   kids      disni
3   solovino dog     None      None
```

Comment: You got the dfs in the wrong order, it should be `animals_updated_df2 = pd.concat([update_df, animals_df])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to tackle your problem.

If you only have this "food" column to handle:

```
animals_updated_df['food'] = animals_updated_df.pop('food_UPDATE').fillna(animals_updated_df['food'])
```

Starting from your `merge` approach. If you have many columns to handle, you could remove the suffix and use a [`groupby.last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.last.html) per column:

```
y_suffix = '_UPDATE'

out = (pd.merge(animals_df, update_df, on=['name', 'animal'],
                how='outer', suffixes=('', y_suffix))
         .rename(columns=lambda x: x.removesuffix('_UPDATE'))
         .groupby(level=0, axis=1).last()
       )
```

The `concat` approach is the most generic one since you can feed it an arbitrary number of dataframes, provided you use the correct order of the dataframes and correct aggregation function (here `groupby.last` since the updated dataframe is second in the `concat`), and you shouldn't have issues with it:

```
out = (pd.concat([animals_df, update_df])
         .groupby(['name', 'animal'], as_index=False, sort=False)
         .last()
       )
```

Output:

```
       name animal      food      brand
0     buddy    dog  dog food  pet smart
1    dexter    cat  Cat Food       None
2  solovino    dog      None       None
3     micky  mouse      kids      disni
```

The error which you report, is very surprising as it's a [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) error, that's typically something that you would get if you used [`numpy.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) instead of `pandas.concat`. Are you sure you haven't use the incorrect function? Out maybe overwritten the pandas method with the numpy's one somewhere in your code?

Comment: Thank you! I really liked the merge approach. I had to modify your code because groupby axis=1 is deprecated. I changed it to 

.T.groupby(level=0, sort=False).last().T

Comment: y_suffix = '_UPDATE'

out = (pd.merge(animals_df, update_df, on=['name', 'animal'],
                how='outer', suffixes=('', y_suffix))
       .rename(columns=lambda x: x.removesuffix(y_suffix))
       .T.groupby(level=0, sort=False).last().T)

Comment: About the NumPy error that is what confused me a lot as well, t was working for at least a year and then it suddenly stopped working, probable there is something in the data that is causing the error. Right now, I do not have time to find why a coded that I will not be using any more stopped working.

Comment: @iDevPy regarding the `concat` issue, it might be a [dtype mismatch or a bug](/q/77151292/16343464)

Answer (score 1):

use `last`, instead `first`

```
pd.concat([animals_df, update_df]).groupby(['name', 'animal'], as_index=False, sort=False).last()
```

Your example can be solved with the above code, but if there are null values in name or animal, desired output will be different.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I have tried this as well. but this code is also throwing me this  error out of the blue after using it for years. ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 12176 and the array at index 1 has size 43 a

Comment: To solve your problem, you need to generate an example that is reproducible. Your example does not reproduce your problem.