# Replace pandas row in one dataframe with row(s) from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames defined like so:

```
left = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": ["a", "b"]})
left["C"] = pd.Series(dtype="int64")

right = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 1], "B": ["a", "a"], "C": [10, 20]})
```

To provide a bit of context here, `right` was derived from `left` and then filtered using `loc`, with additional columns added to the result. As such, where column names match between `left` and `right`, the values should also match, but there will be additional columns in `right` that may or may not be present in `left`. Furthermore, I have many `right`s and each will be merged into `left`, producing a new value for `left`, and the code I'm trying to write here will be part of a for-loop that does this for each `right`.

```
   A   B   C
0  1   a  10
1  1   a  20
2  2   b  NaN
```

I've tried a few ways to handle this.

#### Assigning to loc

In this strategy, I filter the rows using `loc` and then assign to them:

```
left.loc[left["A"] == right["A"]] = right
```

This gets me the correct columns but I'm missing a rows:

```
   A   B   C
0  1   a  10
2  2   b  NaN
```

#### Merging

In this strategy, I employ merging to get the dataset I'm interested in.

```
left.merge(right, on="A", how="left")
```

This gets me all the rows I want but now the columns have to be renamed, which makes it a pain as I expect I'll have an array of `right`s and they'll all need to be merged into `left` so the renaming step would become increasingly annoying. Plus, in this case I'd then have to determine how to merge `left.C` and `right.C` if there are values from both I want to keep.

```
   A B_x   C_x  B_y   C_y
0  1   a   NaN    a  10.0
1  1   a   NaN    a  20.0
2  2   b   NaN  NaN   NaN
```

#### Joining

Similar to the merging strategy, this one revolves around joining the datasets together:

```
left.join(right, on="A", how="left", rsuffix="R")
```

This is actually the worst of both solutions to some extent because now I don't have all the rows I want and the column names are not correct, leaving me with the same column-merging problem I had when using `merge`.

```
   A  B   C   AR   BR    CR
0  1  a NaN  1.0    a  20.0
1  2  b NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

Does anyone know how to get this output? It seems like there should be a simple solution here, but as I can't find it, perhaps there's a more complex operation I need to do?

Comment: Without knowing how you want to implement "Plus, in this case I'd then have to determine how to merge left.C and right.C if there are values from both I want to keep." it's impossible to answer this question

Comment: @Nick Essentially, I have a scenario where `left.C` is NaN or `right.C` is NaN or both are NaN. I want to keep the non-NaN values if they exist or leave it as NaN otherwise.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66786112/9473764) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but it seems like you can use `cumcount` to `merge` with an outer join.

```
out = (left
       .merge(right, left_on=['A', 'B', left.groupby(['A', 'B']).cumcount()], 
              right_on=['A', 'B', right.groupby(['A', 'B']).cumcount()], 
              how='outer', suffixes=['', '_'])
       .sort_values(['A', 'B', 'key_2'])
       .assign(C=lambda x:x['C'].fillna(x.pop('C_')))
       .drop('key_2', axis=1)
)
```

out

out:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   a   10.0
1   1   a   20.0
2   2   b   NaN
```

---

**Update answer**

@Nick advise

if want only merge on 'A', use following Code:

```
out = (left
       .merge(right, left_on=['A', left.groupby('A').cumcount()], 
              right_on=['A', right.groupby('A').cumcount()], 
              how='outer', suffixes=['', '_'])
       .sort_values(['A', 'key_1'])
       .assign(B=lambda x: x['B'].fillna(x.pop('B_')))
       .assign(C=lambda x: x['C'].fillna(x.pop('C_')))
       .drop('key_1', axis=1)
)
```

out

---

check with other example

```
left = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 1, 2], "B": ["a", 'a',"b"], 'C':[float('nan'), 50, 20]})
right = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 1, 1], "B": ["a", "a", 'a'], "C": [10, float('nan'), 30]})
```

left:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   a   NaN
1   1   a   50.0
2   2   b   20.0
```

right:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   a   10.0
1   1   a   NaN
2   1   a   30.0
```

out:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   a   10.0
1   1   a   50.0
2   1   a   30.0
3   2   b   20.0
```

Comment: OP only wants to merge on `A` and update `B` and `C` values...

Answer (score 0):

I've found a potential solution but I don't like it very much:

```
result = left.merge(right, on=["A", "B"], how="left")
result["C"] = result.apply(lambda x: x["C_y"] if pd.isnull(x["C_x"]) else x["C_x"], axis=1)
result = result.loc[:, ~result.columns.str.endswith("_x")]
result = result.loc[:, ~result.columns.str.endswith("_y")]
```

This solution looks neat on the surface, but depends on `left` and `right` having the same values for all columns except `C` and starts to fail hard once you start wanting to merge more than one column. I think this solution would be acceptable without the `apply`, but as is I can't really say I'd want to use it.

Comment: How about `res = left.merge(right, on=["A", "B"], how="left", suffixes=['', '_r']); res['C'] = res['C'].fillna(res.pop('C_r'))` ?

Comment: Note that this solution only copies `C` values, not `B` values

Comment: @Nick That is a very interesting solution

Comment: You could extend it to `B`. I had placed an answer doing that but deleted it because I think you actually want the answer I linked as a comment to the question